# How to match and delete some if statements from a file based on pattern matching

Tags: shell, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have following code

```
if (temp==1) {
some text 
}
some more text 
abcdef
if (temp==1) {
some text 
}
if (temp2==1) {
some text 
}
```

I need to use any script/command to delete all the if statements.

Required output:

```
some more text 
abcdef
if (temp2==1) {
some text 
}
```

What i can already achieve is the following

```
grep -zPo "if\ \(temp==1\) (\{([^{}]++)*\})" filename
```

and i get the following output

```
if (temp==1) {
some text 
}
if (temp==1) {
some text 
}
```

Same result from perl command too

```
perl -l -0777 -ne  
    "print $& while /if \(temp==1\) (\{([^{}]++|(?1))*\})/g" filename
```

Now i need to delete the matched lines from the file.
So all `if(temp2==1)` must be retained and `if(temp==1)` must be deleted.
How can i do this?

Comment: doesn't work with perl regex (Po)

Comment: You say you need to delete all if statements but then your expected output includes an if statement. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: condition is different. 
if (temp2==1) has to be retained and if (temp==1) has to be deleted

Comment: And again: edit the question please.  I've just read through it all, puzzled, to finally see it in a comment.

Comment: edited the question to be more clear. Hope that helps

Comment: If braces may be nested look up "nested delimiters."  One good tool: [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html)

Comment: The OPs real text doesn't look like the simple sample input he's provided (see his comments under https://stackoverflow.com/a/48527696/1745001) so the general answer is "you can't do it without a language parser" since we're now down the rabbit hole of having to deal with nested delimiters, delimiters within strings, within comments, etc., etc..

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking to do is impossible in general without a parser for whatever language that code is written in but you can produce the output you want from that specific input using any awk in any OS on any UNIX box with:

```
awk '/if \(temp==1/{f=1} !f; /}/{f=0}' file
```

if that's all you want.

Comment: Awesome!! works like a charm.. Just checking further.. i will mark this as correct answer once my check finishes.

Comment: it fails when there are nested braces. For example if (temp==1) { something if (temp3==1) { something else } }

Comment: @blganesh101 Your example is in your question, don't ask people to be 'yoda' and know your input out of thin air.

Comment: understood. i am just stating my check. i am absolutely fine with whatever answers given here. thanks for your concern.

Comment: As I said "What you're asking to do is impossible in general without a parser for whatever language that code is written in but you can produce the output you want from that specific input ..." - if your actual input doesn't look like the sample you provided then of course the script will not parse it.

Comment: well i totally get it. but i am just trying to add more cases to test the script. thanks.

Comment: Then you're just wasting everyone's time with the question as written since you're asking how to parse text without showing us a truly representative example of that text.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use `sed` to do this:

```
$ sed '/temp==1/,/}/d' inputfile
some more text 
abcdef
if (temp2==1) {
some text 
}
```

Above deletes (with `d`) all lines between and including the patterns, `/temp==1` and `}`.

Note: It will not work with nested patterns as OP is suggesting in his comment. As per OP's comment, one could do the following:

```
$ sed '/temp==1/,/}/d;/}/,/}/d' 1.txt
```

This removes additional texts and patterns that are between two `}`s.

Comment: it fails when there are nested braces. For example if (temp==1) { something if (temp3==1) { something else } }

Comment: There will always be edge cases with these kinda pattern and no one will be full proof.

Comment: Just my result. it does not work. it deletes all the lines after the first match